# Regression with dependent data with low dependence

Tags: regression, multilevel-analysis, independence

Suppose you have data that is grouped in one way or another and therefore the assumption of independence is suspect. But you look at the intraclass correlation (or autocorrelation) and it is very close to 0 - indicating independence (or, at least, no strong dependence).

In this situation, is there any harm in using a multilevel model anyway (instead of OLS regression)? (e.g. does it lose power?)

Comment: A low sample autocorrelation or intraclass correlation would indicate that those population correlations were small, rather than indicating independence and there are potential costs either way. (The question itself is a great question however)

Comment: Thanks. Doe my edit address your first point?

Comment: Yes. (Sorry, having computer issues for a few days; I missed the reply)

Comment: Would a more specific example be like doing a mixed effects regression (and giving up degrees of freedom for including the computation of the correlation structure for the errors, even when it is absent) instead of a fixed effects regression?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings  That's certainly one example of what I am thinking of

Comment: @PeterFlom but isn't it a bit trivial that power is lost when one is adding useless parameters to determine a (non-existing) more complex (correlated) structure of the errors? Or are you looking for some less simple answers? For instance ideas about the point *when* the independence is low enough that one can consider adding multiple levels becomes useless? Or the degree in which the power is lost?

Comment: I'm really casting a general question here. E.g. yes, it's pretty clear that power is lost by adding useless terms, but the term is almost never completely useless.

Comment: @PeterFlom It is too bad that you did not get any response on this question with your bounty. I have some ideas but not very clear yet and I didn't have much time to think about it. Possibly I might still add some answer.

Comment: @MartijnWeterings I agree. This is the first time I've put up a bounty and gotten no answers at all.

Comment: There are two things that stick out to me here. The first and perhaps most obvious issue for me is the serious risk of non-convergence when the ICC is low. Given low RE variance is often a culprit of failed models in `lme4`, I see that as the biggest statistical "threat." However, I also feel that it becomes another issue of overkill. Surely there may be some group-level differences within a relationship being modeled, but that may not matter all that much if the model does a good enough job of capturing the DGP.